# Method FloatMath.sqrt() is deprecated

Tags: android, android-studio

I updated my android studio to 2.1.2 and opened previous project.Now it shows that FloatMath.sqrt() is deprecated and cannot resolve method 'sqrt(float)'

Comment: Use (float)Math.sqrt(...)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Just type cast it with **float** as -

```
(float)Math.sqrt(...)
```

`FloatMath` is deprecated in API 22

Reference link - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/FloatMath.html

Comment: Please don't answer exact duplicates.

Comment: Indeed, rather add your answer *to* the duplicate.

Comment: Okay. m agree with u @surfian